# How to find out the maximum alignment supported by the linker (on Linux)?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, ld, memory-alignment

I'm trying to find out what is the maximum supported value I could use with `__attribute__((aligned (N)))`.

According to [GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.2.0/gcc/Common-Type-Attributes.html#Common-Type-Attributes) it depends on the linker used:

> On many systems, the linker is only able to arrange for variables to be aligned up to a certain maximum alignment. (For some linkers, the maximum supported alignment may be very very small.)

Is there some way to find this value out? Does it depend on the linker used or the system itself?
In other words, looking at three possible linkers: `ld.bfd`, `lld` and `gold`, will they have the same alignment limit and how to find it out?

Comment: Why don't you just try it out?

Comment: Curious, once you find out the maximum supported value, how will you use that info?

Comment: Just using a high value gives me this result: `main.cpp:8:1: error: requested alignment '1073741824' exceeds maximum 268435456` one system. So that system has max at 2^28

Comment: Same code on another system: `prog.c:8:1: error: requested alignment is too large` but also this system has 2^28 as max

Comment: @4386427 I believe this is compiler's internal implementation limit. Try creating to global values with alignment of 268435456  and check if their address is actually aligned as requested.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I have some software that relies on some value to be aligned a certain way. And it works on one machine, randomly fails on another. I want to 1) confirm that the default linker has alignment limit 2) check if alternative linkers can solve this problem. Manually running 28+ tests for each linker to determine this value seems very suboptimal. Especially when GCC refers to a linker documentation where this value is supposedly documented (but I couldn't find it, hence the question).

Comment: @DanM. Sounds like the max is not needed, just why a certain value works on one and not the other.  Hope you find a solution.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica it's not crucial for "check if the program works correctly with any linker", but since the limit exists, I'd like to be aware of it. So I could know whether something will work or won't, without actually creating a test program. Not to mention that some value can get proper alignment N times without linker actually supporting it just by chance.